# Want to align vertically the beginning of a paragraph with an item of a list

Tags: vertical-alignment, itemize

What I want to do is the following:

```
Item: asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
      asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
      asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
```

I already use `\parbox` for the paragraph but I don't know how to align it that way and `\vspace` did no good to me.

Comment: your question is not at all clear (where (and why!!) do you use parbox?) it would be better to show a small complete tex document than "ascii art" `Item: \parbox[t]{3cm}{asd....}` would produce something like that, but why not use a list?

Comment: I use \parbox to enclose the text next to the item of the list, and the thing is that I don't want another list because I don't want to have different items, I want it to look exactly the way it looks with the Item and the asd's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard markup for the output that you show would be

```
\item[Item] asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
      asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
      asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
```

with a suitable setting for the list parameters, however since you ask for `\parbox`

```
Item: \parbox[t]{5cm}{asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
      asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas
      asdasdasdasdasdasdasdas}
```

The list version would automatically extend to the right margin and allow page breaking within the item, but the `\parbox` version also has uses, notably if you do not want to allow page breaking within the item.